# Is there a way to filter a heatmap based on relevance?

Tags: r, filter, heatmap

I'm currently working with ComplexHeatmap and a very large dataset from RNAseq (~13,000 genes/columns). The heatmap output (based off of clustering) at the moment contains so many columns it's essentially unusable. I'm wondering if there is a method for filtering out the least relevant genes (the darkest/most "far away" clusters) to make the columns of my heatmap less numerous and thus the plot more useful. Any ideas for this? Or any other ideas for getting similar results?

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature selection problem, where you want to select features (genes) that are the most "relevant". It seems that this "relevance" can be measured by how well a feature discriminates among the clusters. This can be assessed simply by running a differential expression analysis among the groups you want to discriminate - the most significant genes are the ones with the strongest associations with the target, and will appear the most visually different on a heatmap. Choose some subset of significant genes, or some fixed number of representative genes, and plot the heatmap only using those genes that are actually discriminative of what you want to show.